# Unconditionally open a URL or launch an application post installation in Inno Setup

Tags: inno-setup

Let's say my Inno Setup script contain following under `[Run]`:

```
Filename: "{app}\{#MyAppExeName}"; \
    Description: "{cm:LaunchProgram,{#StringChange(MyAppName, '&', '&&')}}"; \
    Flags: shellexec postinstall skipifsilent runascurrentuser
```

I want this action to be forcefully performed, like mandatory with checks on disable. Or there is URL which I want to open on Post Install but again with forced, so checks on it be disable.
What is required to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to disable whole checklist, it's as simple as disabling whole `RunList` control:

```pascal
[Code]

procedure InitializeWizard();
begin
  WizardForm.RunList.Enabled := False;
end;
```

[image]

---

If you want to disable the individual checkboxes, you need to know their indexes. What might not be trivial, if their number changes conditionally. But usually it would be easy.

```pascal
[Code]

procedure CurPageChanged(CurPageID: Integer);
begin
  if CurPageID = wpFinished then
  begin
    if WizardForm.RunList.Items.Count >= 1 then
      WizardForm.RunList.ItemEnabled[0] := False;
  end;
end;
```

[image]